# Counting amount of rows by unique ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

got problem with this formula I can't wrap my head around. What I'm trying to do is to **count amount of invoices that are past due per co. id - in other words we're asking the question: HOW MANY OVERDUE INVOICES EACH INDIVIDUAL COMPANY HAS?**

I created an example table here for easier demonstation
The columns go respectively A,B,C etc. Same logic for rows

```
Co. ID | Invoice | Days Past Due
221    | 1812    | 2
221    | 1813    | Not past due yet
221    | 1814    | 5
458    | 3548    | 3
954    | 3214    | Not past due yet
```

Here would be the expected result (in another table)
Let's call the columns D and E for clarity

```
Co. ID | Amount of Overdue Invoices
221    | 2            // <- 2 overdue, 1 not past due = 2 overdue
458    | 1
954    | 0
```

The closest I got to a form that at least somewhat makes some sense was:

```
=COUNTIF($C$2:$C$6, ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP($D$2, $A$2:$A$6, 1, 0))
```

Though obviously that doesnt work, because vlookup returns individual value for index, but that's the closest thing I can think of on how to filter the list.

**Algorhytmically speaking what I'm trying to do:**

1. Divide data by Co. ID (so we only work with data relevant to specific Co. ID)
2. If the in the days past due is a number, increment the result by 1
3. Exit the loop once the Co. ID no longer matches (we only want data relevant to 1 specific company and then move onto the next)
4. Return result (amount of overdue invoices per company ID).

> *Technically I know I could code a vba macro where i would for loop the entire columns and increment i (or whatever variable) based on the
>   fact, if the days past due column is a number, but I'd prefer to do
>   this with formulas if possible.*

Comment: Could you not consider a pivot table? Could the text 'Not past due yet' be replaced with 0?

Comment: @AndyG I'd prefer formula, at the very least for educational purposes. (trying to comprehend some advanced formulas). As to the data, yes, it would be possible to change the String to 0

Comment: @Rawrplus Why are there only 2 overdues for CO. ID 221 when I see 2, Not past due yet and 5 all on respective lines for it? And like Andy G said, if you just change "Not past due yet" to 0, you can easily create a pivot table that takes care of this for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried simply looking for something greater than 0 in the past due column like this

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,G2,C:C,">0")
```

where G2 is "221" Co.ID and that seems to be working.

Comment: Great, thanks. Guess I did completely overthink it...!

Answer (score 0):

You can count the total of invoices - the ones that are not due yet:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A;D2)-COUNTIFS(A:A;D2;C:C;"Not past due yet")
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot completely do it in formulas. It can be done with combination of `formula` and `PIVOT`

Step 1 Create a pivot and drag the co.ID to `Row label`
Step 2 Please the below formula in the next column

`=COUNTIFS($F$6:$F$10,J7,$H$6:$H$10,">=0")`

Change the range Accordingly

so When ever you change the Days past Due just need to Refresh the pivot. it will get you the detail..

[image]